# When CodeIgniter controller starts with capital letter, it gives 404 Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

When I write mysite.com/Site/Home in the browser, it gives me: 404 Page Not Found!, while when change the controller name to small letter (mysite.com/site/Home) it runs well !! How to overcome such issue ?!

Comment: "Doctor, Doctor! It hurts when I do this". "Well don't do that, then"

Comment: It depends on the OS you use. When I run am in Windows can type controller name in any case but in linux it is Case sensitive. Because in linux file names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use "/Site" in the browser then change your class name in the controller to Site and the filename of the file it is in to Site (obviously with all the other data)

Simple as, if you still get an error
don't put Site in your browser, names are case sensitive! CI may not allow the use of capitalized searches.